# How to make a dynamic Flutter button with add2calendar package?

Tags: flutter, dynamic, calendar, widget

New to Flutter. I have this button and on pressed is launching the calendar on device. I want to make this button dynamic as i have more than 20 dates in my model/events.dart list and i want to launch the calendar with the specific date like DateTime('${events.date}') maybe?
Is there another solution for this? Vs Code errors is telling me that i should create a getter to solve this. Thoughts?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:add_2_calendar/add_2_calendar.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../model/events.dart';

class Calendar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CalendarState createState() => _CalendarState();
}

class _CalendarState extends State<Calendar> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldState = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Event event = Event(
      title: '',
      description: '',
      location: '',
      startDate: DateTime.now(),
      endDate: DateTime.now(),
      allDay: false,
    );

    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            FontAwesomeIcons.calendarAlt,
            size: 30.0,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Add2Calendar.addEvent2Cal(event);
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Events {
  final String imagePath,
      title,
      description,
      location,
      duration,
      punchLine1,
      punchLine2,
      address,
      shareB,
      phone,
      fb,
      maps,
      guide,
      date;
  final List categoryIds, galleryImages;

  Events({
    @required this.imagePath,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.description,
    @required this.location,
    @required this.duration,
    @required this.punchLine1,
    @required this.punchLine2,
    @required this.categoryIds,
    @required this.galleryImages,
    @required this.address,
    @required this.shareB,
    @required this.phone,
    @required this.fb,
    @required this.maps,
    @required this.guide,
    @required this.date,
  });
}

final ponteRagogna = Events(
  imagePath: "assets/locations/ponte1.jpg",
  title: "Osteria al Ponte dal Lupo",
  description: "",
  location: "Ragogna",
  duration: "",
  punchLine1: "Osteria",
  punchLine2: " al Ponte dal Lupo",
  address: "Via al Ponte 6, Ragogna",
  maps: "46.184476,12.96572912",
  phone: "+393501073003",
  fb: "https://www.facebook.com/pages/category/Restaurant/Osteria-al-ponte-dal-lupo-2354276691519510/",
  galleryImages: [
    "assets/locations/ponte0.jpg",
    "assets/locations/ponte1.jpg",
    "assets/locations/ponte2.jpg",
  ],
  categoryIds: [
    2,
  ],
  shareB:
      "https://www.tripadvisor.it/Restaurant_Review-g666616-d3964038-Reviews-Osteria_al_Ponte-Cison_Di_Valmarino_Province_of_Treviso_Veneto.html",
  guide: "",
  date: "24-09-2020",
);
```

Comment: Can you please share a sample of `events.dart`?

Comment: I've just posted my events.dart file, i just can't find a way to make date dynamic here

Comment: Have you tried `DateTime(ponteRagogna.date)`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have around 20 events with different dates and i need something like "startDate: DateTime('${events.date}')" from the provider

Comment: I added an answer in the case you want one button per event.

Comment: Is there a significant difference between `Event` class and `Events`?

Comment: still not working, event class is used by add2calendar and i had to modify mine in events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `List<Events>` :

In your events.dart

```dart
final events = [
  ponteRagogna,
  new Events(...)
];
```

In your code :

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    for (var staticEvent in events)
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
         final event = Event(
           title: '',
           description: '',
           location: '',
           startDate: DateTime(staticEvent.date),
           endDate: DateTime(staticEvent.date),
           allDay: false,
         );
         Add2Calendar.addEvent2Cal(event)
        },
      )
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixit by adding startdate, endate to my model file and now is dynamic. Only thing that i can't figure it out now is the hour as i use DateTime.utc(). Is giving me one more hour in the calendar.

```
class Calendar extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldState = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final events = Provider.of<Events>(context);

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.calendarAlt,
              size: 30.0,
              color: Colors.purple,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Event event = Event(
                title: events.title,
                description: events.description,
                location: events.location,
                startDate: events.startDate,
                endDate: events.endDate,
                allDay: false,
              );
              Add2Calendar.addEvent2Cal(event);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way we can add multiple events at once for this package, Or any other plugin that you might have gone through